# isn't possible to use html tags in java comments?

Tags: java, html, tags, comments

I've downloaded a project tutorial developped in java. when I used **mvn clean install**, I figured out that html tags used in comments are not supported and as well i get a Build failure.

I tried to remove those tags and error disappear but the problem I have many files using html tags in comments. Maybe the version I 've installed does not this kind of writting .

`/**
 * (only the method <tt>evaluate</tt>) or more elaborated (conjunction 
 */
public interface RoutingFilter extends Filter {
}`

```
[ERROR]  * (only the method <tt>evaluate</tt>) or more elaborated (conjunction of path
```

Comment: at the moment , i just cloned the project and I want to build it.

Comment: How can i check that ?

Comment: In fact, the problem was that jdk was not in the appropriate  place , i desinstalled and reinstalled and exported java_home and it works. Thank you :)